# How to Protect Android Project

Tags: android, jar, obfuscation

I made a program on Android. But this is my thesis and I have to give my project to my lecturer. Well I dont want to show some of the code that I wrote. Then I want to encrypt something. If I give him the completed project then he can look at every part of the codes.  I don't know Java that well. I was thinking  that I can create something like a dll file in Java (I dont know what it is in Java?) and do some obfuscation. And then I can use this dll file in my project then the lecturer can't see all the code.

I hope I explained it. It's not an apk file. It's a project and I want to hide some code as dll or whatever.

Edit: How do I create a JAR from an Android project?

Comment: The Java equivalent of DLLs are JARs, which operate in almost the same way.

Comment: I see, thanx, I will search how to do it..

Comment: Surely your tutor is going to want to see the logic behind your app in order to mark it?

Comment: then I will say to him, I used some special file (jar files) and I dont know those codes. It was prepared before.. What can I do :)

Comment: It's weird. I thought your tutor will give you better result if you tell him that you did that all?

Comment: He wants some student to improves it. But its not good because its mine :) I have worked over this project in a lot of days but the lecturer will use my project (also he is writing an article about MY PROJECT) its not so fair .. then I will hide somethings. I hide some codes on c# side, it was easy, and now I will try it for android .. i hope i will be able to do it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export your class(es) to JAR file(s), then add them to the build path of your project that will be given to the lecturer.

However, when exporting, remember not to export the source of the classes. I don't know which IDE you are using, but in `Eclipse`, just right click the project, choose `Export`, and check any files you want.

**EDIT: To answer your question in the comment below:**

For example, you have `Operator` class, which has `Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide` static methods in it. Now, you want to call `Add(1, 3)` in your project (which you will give away), and don't want people know how the `Add` method works. So now, when exporting the JAR file, just check the namespace that contains Operator class. Consider the JAR file name is `Operator.JAR`.

Copy the `Operator.JAR` file into your project folder (anywhere will works, but I recommend \lib\Operator.jar). Right click the copied file, choose `Build Path` -> `Add to build path`.

Now in the project, you type in the code `Operator.Add(1, 3)`, Eclipse will tell you it doesn't know what `Operator` is. Press `Ctrl + Shift + O`, it will automically import the needed namespace.

Comment: yes I use Eclipse, I got it, I will right click to my classes to export as jar after i will add jar file which was class before? just that?

Comment: @user1022138 Edited my answer :) Hope it helps.